# Call to undefined function mysqli_init() codeigniter with php hmvc

Tags: php, codeigniter, php-7, php-7.3, hmvc-codeigniter

**hello I have a PHP error**

```
Message: Call to undefined function mysqli_init()
/public_html/system/database/drivers/mysqli/mysqli_driver.php
```

I checked my MySQLi in server and it is working good and I tried to install packages in the server but the server told me that no package available, there are two sites in my server working good buy Codeigniter but this on I used hmvc

I see a lot of answers here but nothing success with me

**NOTE**

the site is working on my localhost

Comment: the `mysqli_driver.php` file is part of the CodeIgniter core. If it's not there, you probably have a incomplete Codeigniter installation or  your `system` directory is not where CodeIgniter expects it to be. Check your main `index.php` file for `$system_path` and double check it points to the correct location of the system directory

Comment: the mysqli_driver.php there, and the site is working in my localhost but on the server there are errors

Comment: Did you install the php mysql extension?  `apt-get install php7.2-mysql`

Comment: @AlexBarker it is CentOS so this command not working and I tried to replace apt with yum still not working

Comment: could you double check in `php.ini` whether `mysqli` extension is there and active. and could you post the command you tried to install php mysql? did you try `sudo yum install php-mysqli`?

Comment: @BagusTesa I tried this `Sudo yum install php-mysqli` and the answer was  `No package php-mysqli available.
Error: Nothing to do`

Comment: Running PHP under Redhat is unpleasant.  I am not sure what version of CentOS you are using, or more importantly where you got PHP.  It says you are using PHP 7.3 in you question, however, no version of Redhat comes with that version of PHP.  If you are not using CentOS 8, you only get PHP 5.4 from upstream.  Check your PHP source for the mysqli extension.  If you compiled it from source, you need to --enable it during the configure process.

Comment: thanks, I solved the problem with your advice, thanks